# JOptionPane message is not read by screen reader

Tags: java, accessibility, joptionpane, screen-readers

I'm developing a software for music education purposes and it has to be accessible by screen reader so blind kids can use it too. But I'm having a problem with JOptionPane messages. They are not read by screen reader.
When I try something like this

```
JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(getContentPane(), "Message", "Title", JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
```

only the title and the buttons are read.

Is there any way I can make the message readable by screen reader? Can I make the message focusable or something?

P.S. Everything else is readable by screen reader (I'm using NVDA) but JOptionPane messages.

**EDIT:**

After VGR suggestion on using JLabel as the message, I got to make the screen reader read the message, but I had to do it like this:

```
JLabel lbl = new JLabel("Message");
lbl.setFocusable(true);
JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(getContentPane(), lbl, "Title", JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
```

But I'm still having a problem. When the JOptionPane opens, the screen reader reads the title and then the first button grabs the focus, so the reading order is: title > buttons > message.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Out of curiosity, does `JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(getContentPane(), new JLabel("Message"), "Title", JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);` produce different results?